# Parse $routeParams in the config object

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to dynamically set the title for each page of my angular app.  I am setting the title of the page in the $routeProvider configuration like so:

```
angular.module('app.assets').config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {
        $routeProvider. 
            when('/assets/:id', {
               templateUrl: 'app/components/assets/views/view.tpl.html',
               controller: 'AssetViewCtrl',
               data : { 
                 pageTitle: 'Assets:id' 
               }               
        });    
}]);
```

The problem is that the page title is now 'Assets:id' verbatim.  Is it possible to parse the value of 'id' similar to the first parameter of the `when`?

i.e  `/assets/:id -> assets/1991`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using data, you might want to resolve the variables:

```
when('/assets/:id', {
      templateUrl: 'app/components/assets/views/view.tpl.html',
      controller: 'AssetViewCtrl',
      resolve: {
          data: ['$route', function($route){
                var obj = {};
                obj.pageTitle = 'assets/' + $route.current.params.id;
                return obj;
           }]
      }
}
```

and then in the controller, inject 'data' (with no quotes). data will be an object with property 'pageTitle' with 'assets/' + :id .

Note that when you resolve, you have to use $route.current.params as $routeParams still has the previous route according to : https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/provider/$routeProvider

In the controller you can do something like:

```
$scope.title = data.pageTitle
```

In the view you can do something like

```
<html app="myApp">
    <title ng-bind="title"></title>
</html>
```